# how to Disallow my sub domain from google crawlers while indexing.

Tags: dns, subdomain

Here is my doubt. I have a website called www.example.com which has indexed in google search engine. where beta.example.com is my testing sub domain. Now the beta.example.com is also getting indexed in google search .

Will you please any one of you help me.

Answer (score 0):

Place a robots.txt file in your subdomain. [Read here for more information](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)

Comment: Hi seff, let me explain with an example if the directory path is var/www/public-html for www.example.com and var/beta/public-html for beta.example.com. www.example.com and beta.example.com shares same files. now how can v solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky one. You may need to potentially involve some .htaccess trickery!

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^beta.example.com$
RewriteRule ^robotx\.txt$ robots-beta.txt
```

Then add:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

to the robots-beta.txt file

This should send all the crawlers (who respect robots.txt) to the correct file with the "Disallow: /" if they are coming from your site's beta subdomain.

Comment: You should also use Google Webmasters to get your sub-domain's listing removed.